# Test Activity started from Service

Tags: android, robolectric

Is it possible to test an Activity was started from an IntentService?

```
YourService svc = Robolectric.buildService(YourService.class).get();

Intent fakeIntent = new Intent();
svc.onHandleIntent(fakeIntent);
```

Service `onHandleIntent()` starts an activity.

How can we find and check that activity?

Notes

- Robolectric 3.1+

Answer (score 1):

```
YourService svc = Robolectric.buildService(YourService.class).get();

Intent fakeIntent = new Intent();
svc.onHandleIntent(fakeIntent);

ShadowService shSvc = shadowOf(svc);
Intent svcStartedIntent = shSvc.getNextStartedActivity();
ShadowIntent shIntent = shadowOf(svcStartedIntent);
assertThat(shIntent.getIntentClass()).isEqualTo(YourActivity.class);
```

### As a generic method

```
public <ServiceType extends Service> boolean activityWasStartedFromService(Class actClass, Class<ServiceType> svClass) {
    ServiceType svc = Robolectric.buildService(svClass).get();

    ShadowService shSvc = shadowOf(svc);
    Intent svcStartedIntent = shSvc.getNextStartedActivity();
    if (svcStartedIntent == null) {
        return false;
    }

    ShadowIntent shIntent = shadowOf(svcStartedIntent);
    return shIntent.getIntentClass() == actClass;
}
```

### Then to use

```
boolean activityStarted = activityWasStartedFromService(YourStartedActivity.class, YourService.class);
assertThat(activityStarted).isTrue();
```

---

Keep in mind that Robolectric's `getNextStartedActivity()` will consume the next activity.  If you run this twice and 1st run was true, the 2nd run will return false.